# Whether my Javascript function is running or not in Angular HTML template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to run a function on page load that is written in JavaScript. I have called that function in ng-init but it is not running.

```
HostedFields.setup( this.client_id, 'custom', {
     id: 'testForm',
     url: 'https://test.mogl.com',
     fields: {
       userDetails: this.userToken,
       styles: {
         'input' : {
           'color': '#0000FF'
         }
       },
       cardNumber: {
         selector: '#card-number'
       }
     },
     callback: () => this.formCallbackHandler});
```

Actually this function will construct an iframe for card detail and then on submit will call function automatically.

Comment: Are you talking about `this.formCallbackHandler`? That is not getting called, by appearances. Did you mean `this.formCallbackHandler()`…?

Comment: No, I am calling about HostFields.setup()

Comment: @deceze I cannot find out a way to check it's running or not?